# Sum array of object value by key and append result to existing object

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm currently struggling with this and I don't really know what to do.

I have array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    rating: "good",
    count: 4,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 2,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 4,
  }
]
```

And what I'm trying to get is:

```
[
  {
    rating: "good",
    count: 4,
    total: 4
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 2,
    total: 6
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 4,
    total: 6
  }
]
```

I know that I need to use array reduce but I don't know how to write code to make a structure of array like this.

Comment: Please add the code you've written to the question. SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you.

Comment: *"I know that I need to use array reduce..."* No, you don't. `reduce` is fine if you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable, tested reducer functions. If you aren't, it's just an overcomplicated loop -- hard to read, easy to get wrong. You need a loop (probably two -- one to do the totals, probably storing them in a `Map`, and one to put the totals on all the objects once you have them).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items by `rating` creating a totals map, with a total for each rating.

We can then use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to get the final result.

```js
const input = [ { rating: "good", count: 4, }, { rating: "bad", count: 2, }, { rating: "bad", count: 4, } ];

// Get the total for each rating...
const totals = input.reduce((acc, { rating, count }) => { 
    acc[rating] = (acc[rating] || 0) + count;
    return acc;
}, {})

// Map to get final result...
const result = input.map(({ rating, count }) => { 
    return { rating, count, total: totals[rating] };
});

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a hash table (object) with values:

```
{
    good: 4,
    bad: 6
}
```

This can be done like this:

```
const initArray = [
  {
    rating: "good",
    count: 4,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 2,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 4,
  }
];
const table = {};
for (let i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
    if (!table[initArray[i].rating]) {
        table[initArray[i].rating] = 0;
    }
    table[initArray[i].rating] += initArray[i].count; //filling the table
}
```

And finally add the values ​​from the table back to the array as a `total` field:

```
for (let i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
    initArray[i].total = table[initArray[i].rating];

}
```

```js
const table = {};

const initArray = [
  {
    rating: "good",
    count: 4,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 2,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 4,
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
    if (!table[initArray[i].rating]) {
        table[initArray[i].rating] = 0;
    }
    table[initArray[i].rating] += initArray[i].count;
}

for (let i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
    initArray[i].total = table[initArray[i].rating];
}

console.log(table, initArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple reference using `reduce` for you.

It would be better if you have post some code to show us what you have tried to solve it as the comments said.

```js
const data = [
  {
    rating: "good",
    count: 4,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 2,
  },
  {
    rating: "bad",
    count: 4,
  }
]

let goodTotal = 0
let badTotal = 0
const result = data.reduce((a,v) =>{
  if(v.rating == 'good'){
    goodTotal += v.count
    v['total'] = goodTotal
   }else{
    badTotal += v.count
    v['total'] = badTotal
   }
  a.push(v)
  return a
},[])
console.log(result)
```